# How to call specific action name using Jaydata web api provider?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jaydata

I have multiple 'HttpGet' actions in my Web Api Controller, I'd like to explicitly tell Jaydata provider to use an specific action name for it's get request, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is not supported right now but it will be supported.
You can add this to our backlog or open a github issue...
If you need this feature badly then you can buy support service from us 
and request this feature.
The other way of solving this is using oData with WebApi where this feature works.

Comment: So is there any example which could help us on oData with WebApi? I found this post: 'How to use JayData with ASP.NET Web API' on jaydata's articles, but it's not what we are looking for!

Comment: This is a good starting point for OData in general - whether you use TypeScript or not - http://jaystack.com/blog/typescript-meets-odata-with-the-help-of-jaydata-and-jaysvcutil

Comment: ASP.NET requires to refactor your WebAPI code (mostly parameters) in order to publish your endpoint through OData. We are planning to release a new JayData version next week. If you share your $metadata, I could ask around in the dev team how will the library support your scenario.